# Maven―Dependencies, static content from remote repository

Tags: maven, build, dependencies, build-process, build-automation

I am a bit new to maven, but I have some experiences with ant and the build process. I would like to do one thing that is kind of driving me nuts:

Given:

1. A remote repository (git, svn, hg,…) that holds static content (like images),
2. one maven project that uses/manages the mentioned repository in the same way as it does with all other dependencies (checkout on install, update whenever updates occur), in other words: the maven project depends on that repository

I finally want to be able to access the content (no *.svn or *.git) and copy it into my build, on build time*.

I want maven to store a local copy of that repository in maven`s local repository (~/.m2/repository) only once on each machine and manage it like all other dependencies.

*I am not trying to build a Java project

Thanks for help!

Comment: The basic mindset of Maven is that each project generate a groupId-artifactId-version artifact which is then stored in your local repository for others to depend on.  If you do not conform to this way of thinking you are going to have a hard time using Maven.  It would be relatively easy to write a small Maven project which generates a jar/zip file with your static content which your projects can then depend on, but you must ensure is unpacked yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've seen, Maven projects don't use version control repositories as external artifacts.  That's a little too fine-grained for what you want, I think.

I've done something similar, when Project A wanted to use resources from Project B.

1. Project B, as part of its build procedure, collected it's resources into a ZIP file and deployed the ZIP file into a maven repository.
2. Project A then references the ZIP file artifact, unpacking it when building to where it needs it.

Look into the [dependency plugin for maven](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/), especially the dependency:unpack and dependency:unpack-dependencies goal.

Have fun

Comment: I already stumbled over the dependency plugin. Does this mean that I need to create my own maven repository which itself contains a *.zip of the static content I would like to use?

Comment: You could have a maven project that deploys the artifact into a repository.  You could also use Ant to do the same thing.  What you want to do is deploy the artifact into the repository.  How you do it is up to you.  It would probably be easier to use a Maven project to do so, but it's not mandatory if you like doing a lot of the work yourself.

Comment: as a beginner I just did not thought about deploying something like nexus to create my on maven repositories. Since a jar is just a zip i can pack my static in such a thing. thanks

Comment: It's my personal opinion that if you're using maven as the build tool for critical applications, you should have a local repository (for mirroring public repositories as well as for deploying your own artifacts).  Solely depending on public repositories is too big a risk.  Fortunately, there are plenty of good, open-source products which mitigate this risk.